# How to access the package by name

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have the model which contains packages and sub packages.So how can we move the pointer to the specific package by the package name.So is there any way to iterate through the model and get the package by name

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Repositore.SQLQuery("SELECT package_id FROM t_package WHERE name=<theName>")
```

That will return a XML result set containing all packages with the name you are looking for. It might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EADATA version="1.0" exporter="Enterprise Architect">
    <Dataset_0><Data><Row><package_id>1</package_id></Row><Row><package_id>2</package_id></Row><Row><package_id>3</package_id></Row></Data></Dataset_0></EADATA>
```

So you can either stuff that in a XML parser or use a regular expression like

```
/package_id>(\d+)/
```

to filter all the package-ids.

In turn simply use

```
Repository.GetPackageById(<found id>)
```

to access the found package(s).

Comment: Can we get the EA.Package type object from this

Comment: see my edition on how to access the package elements

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment, this will work:

```
 List<EA.Package> myPacks = new List<EA.Package>();

public void GOThroughAllPackages(EA.Package        dumpPackage)
    {
        foreach (EA.Package packages in      dumpPackage.Packages)
            {
                       if(packages.Name.ToLower().Equals(requiredPackName))
                   {
                       myPacks.Add(packages);
                       break;
                   }
                GOThroughAllPackages(packages);
            }
}
```

Comment: This does not recurse and just searches the top view packages. (You need to indent your code 4 spaces)

Comment: Well, now it recurses, but what if there are more packages than just one with the name? It returns only the last one (deepest recursion level). Rather it should create a list of packages.

Comment: Well made the changes i am not able to get it right in one go i guess. Currenr version should solve the problem

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it may take several minutes for a large model, whereas the SQL approach does the same in a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution (C#) that doesn't require parsing an xml string:

```
        List<EA.Package> packages = new List<EA.Package>();
        string searchValue = "somePackageName";
        var packageElements = Repository.GetElementSet("select o.Object_ID from t_object o inner join t_package p on p.ea_guid = o.ea_guid where o.Name = '"+searchValue+"'",2);
        foreach (EA.Element packageElement in packageElements) 
        {
            packages.Add(Repository.GetPackageByGuid(packageElement.ElementGUID);)
        }
```

It uses the `Repository.GetElementSet()` with parameter `2` that tells it to accept an SQL query.
Note that this solution will not return root packages as they don't have an `t_object` counterpart.